# Can I make and work with multiple copies of Form1 in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have a program that's working pretty well. It's a character sheet program for a game I'm running. Right now, since it only supports 1 active window, I have to save the existing sheet and open a new one. Thus, I can only work with one sheet at a time.

Is there a way in VS2013 C# winforms that I can work with multiple copies of Form1?

This is definitely a noob question, but I'm having trouble finding help on it.

Comment: Also make sure you're not using ShowModal because that will block your code until the Form closes. Preventing you from opening a second one.

Comment: Yes, just @SLaks explains.  This is far from new or particular to VS 2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a new instance of your class and call `Show()`

```
var newForm = new SomeForm();
newForm.Show();
```

Comment: awesome. I saw some code like that on another post on this site, but it wasn't clear if it would work in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just new up another form:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Show();
```